# How do I change the pen size?

Tags: draw-something

I'm playing Draw Something with someone and I've seen him draw with a thinner "pen" than the one I'm using. How can I use such a thin line? And can I also change the pen width to be wider than the default, not just thinner?

Comment: derp. :P yea lower left corner. 4 different sizes

Comment: So... are you looking for ways to _enlarge_ your pen? I know I've heard of a few _tricks_ if you feel your pen is _inadequate._

Comment: Realize, too, that if they are on an iPad they will be able to do much more detailed pix than if you're using a phone screen, with the "same" pen lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, not sure how I missed it:

You need to click the "pen" icon again while it's already selected.